# resharper 7.1 autocompletion and erase everything on the right

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.1

Suppose I have this line:

```
return _jsonParser.Parse(_fileReader.Read(fileLocation)) ;
```

Then, I remove the "_jsonParser.Parse" part:

```
return (_fileReader.Read(fileLocation)) ;
```

Then I start writing

```
return _csvP(_fileReader.Read(fileLocation)) ;
```

Then I press tab, here's what happens

```
return _csvParser
```

the autocompletion did complete my variable, but it erases all the line on the right.

how to disable this ? In resharper 5.1 I didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the enter key. Enter inserts, tab replaces. ReSharper 8 introduces the ability to configure this.